# Why this slider doesn't work in firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created this slider: http://aszx.altervista.org/ytestfluid/

It does work well in chrome, but not in firefox. Could someone tell me why ?

HTML, CSS, JS:

```
.carousel {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.carousel-inner {
    width: 150%;
    left: -25%;
}
.carousel-inner > .item.next,
.carousel-inner > .item.active.right {
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(33%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(33%, 0, 0);
}
.carousel-inner > .item.prev,
.carousel-inner > .item.active.left {
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-33%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-33%, 0, 0);
}
.carousel-control.left,
.carousel-control.right {
    width: 25%;
}



    $('#myCarousel').carousel({
        interval: 10000
    })
    $('.carousel .item').each(function() {
        var next = $(this).next();
        if (!next.length) {
            next = $(this).siblings(':first');
        }
        next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
        if (next.next().length > 0) {
            next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
        } else {
            $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual issue was your custom css conflicting with the base styles set on bootstrap, the css below works fine for me. replace the following css from your custom css with the one in the below.

```
.carousel-inner > .item.next,
.carousel-inner > .item.active.right {
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(33%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(33%, 0, 0);
}
.carousel-inner > .item.prev,
.carousel-inner > .item.active.left {
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-33%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-33%, 0, 0);
}
.carousel-control.left,
.carousel-control.right {
    width: 25%;
}
```

replaced with

```
.carousel-inner > .item.next,
  .carousel-inner > .item.active.right {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(33%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(33%, 0, 0);
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    left: 0;
  }
  .carousel-inner > .item.prev,
  .carousel-inner > .item.active.left {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-33%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-33%, 0, 0);
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    left: 0;
  }
  .carousel-inner > .item.next.left,
  .carousel-inner > .item.prev.right,
  .carousel-inner > .item.active {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    left: 0;
  }

.carousel-control.left,
.carousel-control.right {
    width: 25%;
}
```

Comment: weird but it works for me when i apply them to your page using inspector, there are glitches on the animation effect but it is because you are appending elements

Comment: Yes, I was talking about glitches. How could I remove it ?

Comment: @xRobot i have updated my answer, hope that helps :)